# Using LINQ Join Multiple Tables in C#

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

```
public void getRECDR(string p)
    {
        try
        {
            DBDataContext Database = new DBDataContext();
            var query = (from z in Database.Table01
                         join x in Database.Table02 on
                            new
                            {
                                t1 = z.drNO,
                                t2 = z.RecNO
                            }
                            equals
                            new
                            {
                                t1 = x.DrNO,
                                t2 = x.RecNO
                            } 
                         join c in Database.Table03 on
                            new
                            {
                                t3 = x.DrNO,
                                t4 = x.TicketNo
                            }
                            equals
                            new
                            {
                                t3 = c.DrNo,
                                t4 = c.TicketNO
                            }
                         where z.drNO == p
                         select new
                         {                                 
                             .../// Record data Here
                         }).FirstOrDefault();
                txtbox.text = query.Record01;
                ....// etc.. etc..
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        { MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString()); }
    }
```

How do you join a table in Linq in the proper way? 
I used to do this but it has an error like "specified cast".

At first, I thought it was because of a duplicate primary key of my header table which I match up primary to foreign key on the details table that I have already deleted, but it still shows the same error.

Is my Linq joining code right?

Please help. Thanks.

--- UPDATE

I tried this one in my MS SQL query if it picks up data it does picks up

```
SELECT * FROM [Database.Table01] INNER JOIN
            [Database.Table02] ON [Database.Table01].drNO = [Database.Table02].DrNO AND [Database.Table01].RecNO = [Database.Table02].RecNO INNER JOIN 
            [Database.Table03] ON [Database.Table01].DrNO = [Database.Table03].DrNO AND [Database.Table02].TicketNo = [Database.Table03].TicketNo
WHERE [Database.Table01].drNO = '00884'
```

this query statement picks up data but when i do it on my linq it says "specified cast is not valid".. and it has the same record storage same connection.

Comment: What is your linq provider? Does it support joins on anonymous types?

Comment: sorry what's a linQ provider?? i am using visual studio 2010 and MS SQL server for my database.. is that what your asking?

Comment: ok.. i never made one sir i just call the datacontext in each time i have to make changes in my record..

Comment: Are you using Entity Framework?

Comment: yes sir.. i am using Entity Framework.. i just want to know if my joining of table is right or do anyone have a much nice and stable way on creating a linq expression join multiple table somewhat in a lambda expression..

Comment: You should maybe think to relate the table on your model, so that you can query the table in this way Database.Table1.Include("Table2").Include("Table3"). give a look at this article http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj713564.aspx

Comment: The proper way to join table is to build relations when possible. The error maybe on txtbox.text = query.Record01 where Record01 is not of string type ? Check also the data type of RecNO and TicketNo in the database I suspect that RecNo is different type of TicketNo

Comment: Looks like the error has nothing to do with the code provided. If you provided the actual code, maybe I could look at it again.